# Implementing a data extraction pipeline with Bash

Tags: python, bash, database, etl

I wrote the following scripts to extract data from BigQuery and InfluxDB using the [bigquery cli](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool) and the [influx cli](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/shell/). The code works as expected. I included all files for completeness, but I'm primarily interested in feedback on the bash scripts `config_query.sh`, `extract.sh` and `run.sh`. You can also comment on the python file and on my queries, if you want, but the focus should be on my bash scripts. The overall goal is to make the scripts as maintainable and reliable as possible, execution speed doesn't matter.

This is how the pipeline works on a high level: The queries are saved in textfiles in the folder `/app/queries`. First these textfiles are configured via `config_query.sh`, by replacing the start and end strings of the queries. Then `extract.sh` passes the configured queries to the respective cli's and saves the data in `/app/tmp/raw`. The raw data is then processed and cleaned via `transform.py` and saved to `/app/tmp/clean`. Finally, all these steps are run via `run.sh`. If `config_query.sh` sets up a range between the start and end date that is longer than five days, `run.sh` splits up the queries into chunks of five days in order to avoid a timeout of the server.

This is an overview the directory structure:

```
app/
├── queries/
│   └── gads.sql
│   └── leads.flux
│   └── li.sql
│   └── ms.sql
│   └── subs.flux
├── src/
│   └── config_query.sh
│   └── extract.sh
│   └── transform.py
└── tmp/
    ├── clean/
    │   └── gads.csv
    │   └── leads.csv
    │   └── li.csv
    │   └── ms.csv
    │   └── subs.csv
    ├── raw/
    │   └── gads.csv
    │   └──leads.csv
    │   └── li.csv
    │   └── ms.csv
    │   └── subs.csv
    └── gads_startdate_enddate.csv
    └── leads_startdate_enddate.csv
    └── li_startdate_enddate.csv
    └── ms_startdate_enddate.csv
    └── subs_startdate_enddate.csv
```

Example queries in `/app/queries`:

```
# BigQuery query:
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT
    *
    FROM
        UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2022-01-01', DATE_SUB('2022-01-01', INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS date
), gads_data AS (
    SELECT DATE(__hevo_report_date) AS date,
        campaign,
        ad_group,
        sum(impressions) AS impressions,
        sum(clicks) AS clicks,
        ROUND(sum(cost)/1000000, 2) AS spend
    FROM `example_table`
    WHERE DATE(__hevo_report_date) >= '2022-01-01' AND DATE(__hevo_report_date) < '2022-01-01'
    GROUP BY date, campaign, ad_group
)

SELECT *
FROM dates
LEFT OUTER JOIN gads_data
ON dates.date = gads_data.date

# Influx query:
from(bucket: "example_bucket")
  |> range(start: 2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, stop: 2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z)
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: sum, column: "val")
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```

Here are the scripts:

`config_query.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Configures start date and end date of query files

START_DATE=$1
END_DATE=$2

# Setup directories
HOME="/app"
F1="${HOME}/queries/leads.flux"
F2="${HOME}/queries/subs.flux"
F3="${HOME}/queries/gads.sql"
F4="${HOME}/queries/ms.sql"
F5="${HOME}/queries/li.sql"

# Replaces 'start' and 'stop' in Influx queries:
for f in $F1 $F2
do
  sed -i -E  "s/start: .{4}-.{2}-.{2}T00:00:00.000Z, stop: .{4}-.{2}-.{2}/start: ${START_DATE}T00:00:00.000Z, stop: ${END_DATE}/g" $f
done

# Replaces 'START_DATE' and 'END_DATE' in Bigquery queries:
for f in $F3 $F4 $F5
do
  sed -i -E  "s/\('.{4}-.{2}-.{2}', DATE_SUB\('.{4}-.{2}-.{2}',/\('$START_DATE', DATE_SUB\('$END_DATE',/g" $f;
  sed -i -E  "s/>= '.{4}-.{2}-.{2}'/>= '$START_DATE'/g" $f;
  sed -i -E  "s/< '.{4}-.{2}-.{2}'/< '$END_DATE'/g" $f;
done
```

`extract.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Saves query output to csv-files in folder tmp/raw

# Setup filepaths:
ROOT="/app"
QUERIES="${ROOT}/queries"
RAW="${ROOT}/tmp/raw"

# Setup query paths:
Q1="${QUERIES}/leads.flux"
Q2="${QUERIES}/subs.flux"
Q3="${QUERIES}/gads.sql"
Q4="${QUERIES}/ms.sql"
Q5="${QUERIES}/li.sql"

# Setup target paths:
F1="${RAW}/leads.csv"
F2="${RAW}/subs.csv"
F3="${RAW}/gads.csv"
F4="${RAW}/ms.csv"
F5="${RAW}/li.csv"

# Check if connection to BigQuery works:
bq query --dry_run --use_legacy_sql=false < $Q3 > $F3
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
 echo "No connection to BigQuery possible. Program exiting."
 exit $?;
fi

# Run queries:
for ((i=1;i<=5;i++))
do
    if (( $i <= 2 )); then
      # run influx
      eval "influx query --file \$Q${i} -r > \$F${i} && echo '$(date): Extracted \$Q${i} to \$F${i}...'";
    else
      # run bq
      eval "(bq query -q --use_legacy_sql=false --format=csv --max_rows=100000 < \$Q${i}) > \$F${i} && echo '$(date): Extracted \$Q${i} to \$F${i}...'";
    fi

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
     echo "An error occurred. Program exiting."
     exit $?;
    fi

done
```

`transform.py`:

```
import pandas as pd

# Setup directories:
ROOT_DIR = '/app'
RAW_DIR = ROOT_DIR + '/tmp/raw'
CLEAN_DIR = ROOT_DIR + '/tmp/clean'

# Setup Schemas:
SCHEMA = ['date', 'campaign', 'ad_group', 'impressions', 'clicks', 'spend']
SCHEMA_LI = ['date', 'campaign', 'impressions', 'clicks', 'spend']
SCHEMA_LEADS = ['date', 'path', 'leads', 'registrations', 'trials',
                'basic-trial', 'business-trial', 'education-trial', 'enterprise-trial']
SCHEMA_SUBS = ['New_ID', 'subscription', 'date', 'total_subscriptions',
               'new_subscriptions', 'isTrial', 'offer', 'segment']


def transform_li():
    try:
        # Read Data
        file = RAW_DIR + '/li.csv'
        df = pd.read_csv(file, header=0)
        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        df.insert(0, 'New_ID', range(0, 0 + len(df)))

    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError("Your query output does not conform to the specified schema."
                       "Have you perhaps used 'bq query --dry_run'?")

    except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=SCHEMA_LI.insert(0, 'NEW_ID'))

    finally:
        # Save Data
        path_to = CLEAN_DIR + '/li.csv'
        df.to_csv(path_to, index=False)


def transform_ms():
    try:
        # Read Data
        file = RAW_DIR + '/ms.csv'
        df = pd.read_csv(file, header=0)
        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        df.insert(0, 'New_ID', range(0, 0 + len(df)))

    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError("Your query output does not conform to the specified schema."
                       "Have you perhaps used 'bq query --dry_run'?")

    except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=SCHEMA.insert(0, 'NEW_ID'))

    finally:
        # Save Data
        path_to = CLEAN_DIR + '/ms.csv'
        df.to_csv(path_to, index=False)


def transform_gads():
    try:
        file = RAW_DIR + '/gads.csv'
        df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', header=0)
        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        df.insert(0, 'New_ID', range(0, 0 + len(df)))

    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError("Your query output does not conform to the specified schema."
                       "Have you perhaps used 'bq query --dry_run'?")

    except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=SCHEMA.insert(0, 'NEW_ID'))

    finally:
        # Save Data
        path_to = CLEAN_DIR + '/gads.csv'
        df.to_csv(path_to, index=False)


def transform_subs():
    try:
        # Read Data
        file = RAW_DIR + '/subs.csv'
        df = pd.read_csv(file,
                         header=3,
                         usecols=['_time', '_value', 'added_values', '_field',
                                  'isTrial', 'offer', 'segment', 'sub_values'])
        df.rename(columns={'_field': 'subscription',
                           '_time': 'date',
                           '_value': 'total_subscriptions',
                           'added_values': 'new_subscriptions',
                           'sub_values': 'lost_subscriptions'}, inplace=True)
        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
        df['date'] = df['date'] - pd.Timedelta(days=1)
        df.insert(0, 'New_ID', range(0, 0 + len(df)))

    except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=SCHEMA_SUBS.insert(0, 'NEW_ID'))

    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError("Your query output does not conform to the specified schema."
                       "Have you perhaps used 'bq query --dry_run'?")

    finally:
        # Save Data
        path_to = CLEAN_DIR + '/subs.csv'
        df.to_csv(path_to, index=False)


def transform_leads():
    try:
        # Read Data
        file = RAW_DIR + '/leads.csv'
        df = pd.read_csv(file, header=3, usecols=['_time', 'val', 'path', '_field'])

        # Transform Data
        df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='val', index=['_time', 'path'], columns='_field').reset_index()
        df['trials'] = df['basic-trial'] + df['education-trial'] + df['business-trial'] + df['enterprise-trial']
        df.rename(columns={'_time': 'date',
                           'registration': 'leads',
                           'registration_completed': 'registrations'}, inplace=True)
        df = df.astype({'leads': int,
                        'registrations': int,
                        'trials': int,
                        'basic-trial': int,
                        'business-trial': int,
                        'education-trial': int,
                        'enterprise-trial': int})
        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
        df['date'] = df['date'] - pd.Timedelta(days=1)
        cols = SCHEMA_LEADS
        df = df[cols]
        df.insert(0, 'New_ID', range(0, 0 + len(df)))

    except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=SCHEMA_LEADS.insert(0, 'NEW_ID'))

    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError("Your query output does not conform to the specified schema."
                       "Have you perhaps used 'bq query --dry_run'?")

    finally:
        # Save Data
        path_to = CLEAN_DIR + '/leads.csv'
        df.to_csv(path_to, index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Execute all functions in transform.py
    import transform
    for i in dir(transform):
        item = getattr(transform, i)
        if callable(item):
            item()
```

`run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Run config_query.sh, extract.sh and transform.py.
# Split up jobs in chunks of 5 days if start date and end date are far apart.

# Example usage: ./run.sh start_date end_date

# pass date in format YYYY-mm-dd:
start=$1
end=$2

# Check if start and end are valid dates
for date in $start $end
do
  # Check format
  format="^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$"
  if [[ $start =~ $format && $end =~ $format ]]
    then
      echo "Date $1 is in valid format (YYYY-MM-DD)"
    else
      echo "Date $1 is in an invalid format (not YYYY-mm-dd)."
      exit $?
  fi

# Check if date value is valid
  date -d $date
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "${date} is not a valid date. Enter a valid date."
   exit $?
  fi
done

# Setup root directory path
ROOT="/app"

# Setup clean files directory paths
CLEAN_GADS="${ROOT}/tmp/clean/gads.csv"
CLEAN_LEADS="${ROOT}/tmp/clean/leads.csv"
CLEAN_LI="${ROOT}/tmp/clean/li.csv"
CLEAN_MS="${ROOT}/tmp/clean/ms.csv"
CLEAN_SUBS="${ROOT}/tmp/clean/subs.csv"

# Setup output paths
GADS="${ROOT}/tmp/gads_${start}_${end}.csv"
LEADS="${ROOT}/tmp/leads_${start}_${end}.csv"
LI="${ROOT}/tmp/li_${start}_${end}.csv"
MS="${ROOT}/tmp/ms_${start}_${end}.csv"
SUBS="${ROOT}/tmp/subs_${start}_${end}.csv"

# Delete previously created reports
find $ROOT/tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete

# Setup schema for output paths
echo "New_ID,date,campaign,ad_group,impressions,clicks,spend" > "$GADS"
echo "New_ID,date,path,leads,registrations,trials,basic-trial,business-trial,education-trial,enterprise-trial" > "$LEADS"
echo "New_ID,date,campaign,impressions,clicks,spend" > "$LI"
echo "New_ID,date,campaign,ad_group,impressions,clicks,spend" > "$MS"
echo "New_ID,subscription,date,total_subscriptions,new_subscriptions,isTrial,offer,segment,lost_subscriptions" > "$SUBS"

# Download data in 5-day chunks:
while [[ "$start" < "$end" ]]; do

  temp=$(date -I -d "$start + 5 day")

  if [[ "$temp" < "$end" ]]; then
    ./src/config_query.sh $start $temp && ./src/extract.sh && python ./src/transform.py
  else
    ./src/config_query.sh $start $end && ./src/extract.sh && python ./src/transform.py
  fi

  # Append data to files
  tail -n +2 "$CLEAN_GADS" >> "$GADS"
  tail -n +2 "$CLEAN_LEADS" >> "$LEADS"
  tail -n +2 "$CLEAN_LI" >> "$LI"
  tail -n +2 "$CLEAN_MS" >> "$MS"
  tail -n +2 "$CLEAN_SUBS" >> "$SUBS"

  start=$(date -I -d "$start + 5 day")
done
```

Comment: You could start with [shellcheck](http://ix.io/3SdB).

Answer (score 2):

I see some of this code is an earlier version of [your similar question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/275567/change-query-strings-with-a-bash-script).
Most of the points in the answers on that questions are relevant here too,
let me just call out the highlights here:

- For robustness and simplicity, consider using template files with placeholders to generate scripts with computed values
- Make sure `exit $?` comes right after the relevant command, or save `$?` in a variable to exit later.
- Always enclose variables in double-quotes used on the command line
- To give a name to logic in a block of code, consider defining a function
- Avoid repeated `sed -i` on the same file with different commands by using a single command with mulitple `-e` expressions

In addition to the above, I have a few more ideas about the different parts of the code here.

#### Use arrays instead of numbered variables and `eval`

I'm referring to this part:

> ```
> eval "influx query --file \$Q${i} -r > \$F${i} && echo '$(date): Extracted \$Q${i} to \$F${i}...'";
> ```

`eval` is strongly discouraged,
it seems it was used here to be able to loop over numbered variables.
A better alternative is using an array,
replacing `eval` with array indexing.
You already did that in the later version of the script, and that's great.

#### Reconsider a loop when it does different things depending on the counter variable

The loop in `extract.sh` has a condition on the counter variable,
and does something different when the counter <= 2 and when it's above.
This would be better as 2 loops without a condition on the counter.

Consider something like:

```
die() {
  local exit_code=$?
  echo "An error occurred. Program exiting."
  exit "$exit_code"
}

influx_query() {
  local query=$1
  local out=$2
  influx query --file "$query" -r > "$out" && echo "$(date): Extracted $query to $out..."
}

for ((i = 0; i < 2; i++)); do
  influx_query "${Q[i]}" "${F[i]}" || die
done

for ((i = 2; i < ${#Q[@]}; i++)); do
  bq_query "${Q[i]}" "${F[i]}" || die
done
```

#### Use functions generously

Here:

> ```
> if [[ "$temp" < "$end" ]]; then
>   ./src/config_query.sh $start $temp && ./src/extract.sh && python ./src/transform.py
> else
>   ./src/config_query.sh $start $end && ./src/extract.sh && python ./src/transform.py
> fi
> ```

Instead of duplicating the long `... && ... && ...` twice,
I would create a function that takes start and end date parameters.

```
config_query() {
  local start=$1
  local end=$2
  ./src/config_query.sh "$start" "$temp" && ./src/extract.sh && python ./src/transform.py
}

if [[ "$temp" < "$end" ]]; then
  config_query "$start" "$temp"
else
  config_query "$start" "$end"
fi
```

#### Making scripts more reliable

Since you seem to be interested in making scripts more reliable,
I recommend running `shellcheck` on your scripts and fixing what you find.

Also, to mitigate the impact of certain mistakes,
I start all my Bash scripts with this:

```
set -euo pipefail
```

This does a bunch of helpful things:

- `-e` makes the script abort on the first failing command, which can help in many ways

  - avoid disasters by failing fast
  - highlight that something unexpected happened
  - make the failure easy to see, at the end of the script output
  - encourages implementing solid error handling
- `-u` makes it an error when referencing an undefined variable; together with `-e`, this again can help avoid disasters
- `-o pipefail` makes the exit code of a pipeline success only when all commands exit with success (you can read more about it in `man bash`, search for "pipefail")

#### Use lowercase variable names in scripts

The SHOUT_CASE naming convention is recommended for exported variables for lower level system commands,
such as `PATH`, `HOME`, `EDITOR`, and so on.